# Can I use MS Azure Custom Translator running in a local Docker Container?

Tags: azure, docker

My problem is that I want to create a custom offline translator using my own data to train the translation model. I found out through research that MS Azure provides a framework to build a custom translator like that and run the translator after deploying in a docker container. For my application it is very important that I need an offline translator running on a local machine without having a connection to the world wide web.

**My question:** Is it possible to run the customized translator model locally on a docker container or do I need an connection to the world wide web?

Please feel free to suggest other options or examples of customizable offline translators which I can possibly use for my application.

Comment: I don't think you can, otherwise how Microsoft would make money? Have you investigated  opensource solutions like OpenNMT? https://opennmt.net/

Comment: Yes, I found ArgosTranslate as a possible solution, but it's not that easy to custom the translator like in MS Azure.

Comment: I've read that I can run the MS Translator as an image in docker, but I don't know if I need a constant connection to the worl wide web, when I run the docker image on my local machine!?